# Preserving production order in ANTLR AST

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

For a grammar like, how to preserver the order in which productions appear.

```
class: 'class' ID 
        '{' (fields 
         | methods) * '}'         -> ^(CLASS ID ^(FIELD fields*) ^(METHOD methods) 
         ;
```

The production works as I expect, but if there's a class like

```
class abc {
   field 1 
   field 2
   method 1
   method 2
   field 3
   method 3
   field 4
}
```

All of the fields end up in single list and the methods in second list. What is the correct way of preserving their order? I tried doing..

```
class: 'class' ID 
        '{' (fields               -> ^(FIELD fields)
         | methods                -> ^(METHOD methods)
         )* '}'                   -> ^(CLASS ID $class)
         ;
```

I even tried inserting a dummy head in between with no luck.

```
class: 'class' ID 
        '{' (fields 
         | methods) * '}'         -> ^(CLASS ID ^(FIELD fields*) ^NODE ^(METHOD methods) 
         ;
```

but this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this first case, the `CLASS` node contains a series of `FIELD` nodes (`FIELD fields*`) followed by a series of `METHOD` nodes (`METHOD methods*`) because the production explicitly states that `field` expressions be processed together and then `method` expressions be processed together:

```
-> ^(CLASS ID ^(FIELD fields*) ^(METHOD methods)
```

You didn't mention what the second and third approaches produced, but it was probably less ideal than the first.

Try the following approach with a `body` expression instead:

```
grammar temp;
options {output=AST;}
tokens { KLASS; FIELD; METHOD; }

klass   :   'class' ID body -> ^(KLASS ID body)
        ;

body    :   '{'!
                (field | method) *
            '}'! 
        ;

field   : 'field' INT -> ^(FIELD INT)
        ;

method  : 'method' INT -> ^(METHOD INT)
        ;

ID      : ('a'..'z')+;
INT     : ('0'..'9')+;
WS      : (' '|'\r'|'\n')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;} ;
```

You'll get the following AST result:

```
-KLASS
   -abc
   -FIELD
      -1
   -FIELD
      -2
   -METHOD
      -1
   -METHOD
      -2
   -FIELD
      -3
   -METHOD
      -3
   -FIELD
      -4
```

If you'd like to test the grammar with ANTLRWorks, open (or create) the grammar with it:

[image]

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to start the debugger (don't use the interpreter, it's buggy!):

[image]

Paste your input in the window that pops up and make sure you select the correct start production rule (`klass`, in this case). Then press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

When the debugger is launched, press the *end-arrow* button <kbd>>|</kbd> to parse the input and then click the <kbd>AST</kbd> button to see what the AST the parser created looks like:

[image]

Comment: Didn't notice you also posted an answer... I'll remove mine since yours is correct and posted before my edit :)

Comment: @BartKiers That's very generous of you, thank you. I wasted at least 30 minutes trying to get ANTLRWorks to work, then gave up and wrote my own test app, hence my pretty ASCII output. :P

Comment: No problem. Let me add some extra info in your answer on how to test with ANTLRWorks.

Comment: Great answer! I'd +1 again if I could :)